# Is it possible to use something besides emulsion to directly record the image of a nighttime object using a telescope?

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, photography

The following questions have got me thinking.

- [Is it possible to use Photolithography for telescope image sensor?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40734/7982)
- [Fresnel lenses for a makeshift Galilei telescope?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40880/7982)
- [Has anyone ever tried to make a simple telescope using ice?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27760/7982)

A long time ago I think I wrote an answer, or maybe just a series of comments in a different SE site. *I think* it was Biology SE, and I described ways that people used algae or mold or moss or something in a petrie dish to record a projected image; it photosynthesized faster and grew faster in the brighter areas of the projection.

That's too slow for recording an astronomical image from a telescope.

I don't think the image of the moon from an amateur telescope would be bright enough to burn itself into a small, smooth piece of wood, but I remember something about secret messages written in lemon juice that revealed themselves upon gentle warming.

Is there any way to permanently record a *nighttime* astronomical image without using a digital imager or photographic emulsion?

Comment: Pen, pencil and paper?

Comment: xkcd what if has an article about using moonlight to burn (it can't happen for entropy reasons) https://what-if.xkcd.com/145/ That would also rule out the lemon juice (which works by charring)

Comment: @JamesK thanks for the reference! It cites conservation of *étendue* which is discussed in my answer to [Can a telescope ever increase the apparent luminance of an extended object?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38395/7982). Conversely, a new answer posted to that question citing your link is sorely needed.

Comment: @JohnHoltz That's certainly how Galileo did it.

Comment: @MichaelC and how Schiaparelli documented Mars' *canali*.